# Gunicorn and flask, static files are incomplete/truncated

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I'm having a problem with files being truncated in my combination of gunicorn and flask. For example, Firefox isn't downloading my entire jquery.js file. Using just flask I don't have the problem, and it appears that non-static results are all fine (as are small static files).

My gunicorn config file looks like this:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:80'
workers = 8
worker_class = 'eventlet'
accesslog = '/var/log/search-interface.log'
errorlog = '/var/log/search-interface.log'
loglevel = 'info'
```

I setup the static path in Flask like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='static')
```

Any ideas on why my files are being truncated?

---

Testing with curl I get output like `transfer closed with 72835 bytes remaining to read`.

If I disable 'eventlet' as the worker class it appears to work. However, I am using this class because it works on AWS behind a load-balanced, no other class appears to work there.

Comment: If the problem is having something that works on AWS and you're in hurry then try witth uWSGI instead of gunicorn. Should be nearly a dropin replacement.

Comment: I'll try uwsgi, but I'd like to know if I can fix the above problem before abandoning gunicorn.

Comment: sure, that's why i wrote this in a comment :)

Comment: are you using nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems similar to gunicorn issues [#615](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/615) and [#1155](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1155).

The latter fix the problem and I could confirm the issue I had with gunicorn version `19.4.1` (default as of today in [Fedora 25](https://src.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/python-gunicorn.git/log/?h=f25)) was solved after an upgrade (to `19.7.1`, latest today in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gunicorn/)).